# Htaccess rewrite to remove .php extension not working with directories

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm using this code to "remove" .php extensions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

So I can go to `mysite.com/about` instead of `mysite.com/about.php`.

It works fine but when I have a directory like:

`mysite.com/admin` (inside there I have a index.php) it throws a Forbidden 403 error. How can I fix this?

Btw, if I go to `mysite.com/admin/index` it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is caused because you don't exclude directories. Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```